# key comparisons in c++ map not working

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have created a map with `ClassExpression` as the key and `std::string` as the value. The key comparator is given below

```
class ClassExpressionComparator {
public:
    bool operator()(const ClassExpression& lhs,
    const ClassExpression& rhs) const {
           return ((lhs.quantifier == rhs.quantifier) &&
                   (lhs.property.compare(rhs.property) == 0) &&
                   (lhs.concept.compare(rhs.concept) == 0));
    }
 };
```

ClassExpression contains the 3 fields mentioned in the comparator. I compare all the 3 fields. When I use find() of map, even if the key is not present in the map, it says that it found the key and gives an existing key as the result (getting first key as the result).

I tried the following

```
boost::shared_ptr< std::map<ClassExpression, std::string, 
ClassExpressionComparator> > cemap(
                new std::map<ClassExpression, 
                std::string, ClassExpressionComparator>());
ClassExpression ce1;
ce1.quantifier = com::xxxx::kb::SOME;
ce1.property = "<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/acts-on>";
ce1.concept = "<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/Tissue>";
populateMap(cemap, ce1);

ClassExpression ce2;
ce2.quantifier = com::xxxx::kb::SOME;
ce2.property = "<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/contained-in>";
ce2.concept = "<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/HeartValve>";
populateMap(cemap, ce2);

ClassExpression ce3;
ce3.quantifier = com::xxxx::kb::SOME;
ce3.property = "<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/has-location>";
ce3.concept = "<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/Endocardium>";

std::map<ClassExpression, std::string, ClassExpressionComparator>::iterator
                       ceIterator = cemap->find(ce3);
if (ceIterator == cemap->end()) {
         std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
}
else {
     std::cout << "Found; concept = " << ceIterator->second << std::endl;
}
ClassExpressionComparator cmp;
std::cout << "compare: " << cmp(ce1, ce3) << std::endl;
```

`populateMap()` just does an insert, in my actual code, I do a few more things in it, I wanted to keep the same flow, so left it that way.
The output of `cmp(ce1, ce3)` is 0 but when I do a `find(ce3)`, the result is that it found it at the first key position instead of returning `end()`. Where am I going wrong here?

Thank you.

Raghava.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You wrote an equality comparison. `map` requires a less-than comparison. (Or greater-than if you want the keys in decreasing order.)

My usual idiom for doing this:

```
bool operator()(const ClassExpression& lhs,
const ClassExpression& rhs) const {
       return lhs.quantifier < rhs.quantifier? true
            : rhs.quantifier < lhs.quantifier? false
            : lhs.property.compare(rhs.property) < 0? true
            : lhs.property.compare(rhs.property) > 0? false
            : lhs.concept.compare(rhs.concept) < 0;
}
```

Comment: That is a clever & short way of checking for < among all the members :). If it has to be either < or > for keys then how does a find(key) operate? How can it find the exact key with < operator? With this in mind, I implemented a equality instead of <

Comment: @Raghava: If and only if `a == b`, then `a < b` and `a > b` are both false. And `a > b` is the same as `b < a`. `find` performs both `a < b` and `b < a` at every step. Thinking another way, there are three possibilities: `==`, `<`, and `>`. To eliminate two using Boolean functions, you will need two function calls. So the most efficient, simplest way is to call the same function twice with reversed operands. (Of course, the compiler might optimize both down to one comparison instruction.)

Comment: find uses the assumption that if : !(l < r) && !(r < l) is true then l and r are considered a match.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: As I'm sure you are are well aware since C++ is what it is it's certainly possible that !(l < r) && !(r < l) is true but l === r is false. 

IIRC in the c++ standard they call objects that l === r equals true for equal and objects where !(l < r) && !(r < l) equals true for equivalent to differentiate between this.

Comment: aah, got it. @Potatoswatter & @FuleSnabel: Thank you :). My code is working as expected now. I have another question - a lookup operation in a map is supposed to take constant time right, with the way you have described, in worst case it will take linear (on the size of map) time isn't it.

Comment: @Raghava: It's logarithmic with the size of the map. `find` is a recursive tree descent. The height of a balanced tree is logarithmic with the number of nodes.

Comment: @Fule: If you want to insert equivalent objects, use `multimap`.

Answer (score 2):

The `map` is a sorted container, the comparator operator it's looking for is one that implements a strict weak ordering, like `<`.  You're giving it an equals operator, which will screw up the ordering.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please see my comment on Potatoswatter's post.